# Querying Web Servers from the Linux Terminal

Tags: linux, http, web, fedora

Is it Possible to query a web page from the terminal in Linux?

Edit: To be more specific, my intention is to send POST data to a php page and display the return text. hld619 showed me what cURL is and it works perfectly.

Comment: Define "query a web page."  You can make a request to a web resource with something as simple as `wget`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try looking for [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/), if you are looking for post or get type request, that could be done too

Answer (score 1):

You can browse the web using [Lynx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_%28web_browser%29) in Linux. It's a pretty cool terminal-based web browser. If you're running a Debian (or other `apt`-possessing OS) you can run:

```
sudo apt-get install lynx
```

To get it. You would exclude `sudo` if you have root access.

If by "query a web site" you mean get its source, you can use `curl` or `wget`. Also, your favorite programming language probably has tools to rip the source of websites.

Some popular ones are:

- Python - urllib2
- Ruby - net/http
- Java - JSoup